# Android 12 targetSDKVersion 31 challenges (Broadcast Receiver, Pending Intent) Crash Issues

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-pendingintent, targetsdkversion

Below are the challenges I faced so far when running an Android app with **targetSDKVersion 31** on a phone with OS Version **Android 12**

**1) App is not getting uploaded to store**
Error :- You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without the **'android:exported'** property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported

**2) App is getting crashed**
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles. **FLAG_IMMUTABLE / FLAG_MUTABLE** tag is required for all Pending Intents

Please help how to address these issues ????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) App is not getting uploaded to store Error :-** You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without the 'android:exported' property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported

**Solution :-** Targeting from 12, If in case any of your activity/service/receiver in your AndroidManifest.xml of your app or in any library is using intent-filter  then it should have android:exported tag specified explicitly. You can select the **MergerManifest** option in AndroidManifest.xml to identify which library has Services and Activities.

**2) App is getting crashed**
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles. **FLAG_IMMUTABLE / FLAG_MUTABLE** tag is required for all Pending Intents

**Solution:-** Add FLAG_IMMUTABLE for all the PendingIntents. If your PendingIntent already has a flag then append this by using |. Eg:- **FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | FLAG_IMMUTABLE**, **FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT | FLAG_IMMUTABLE**

Comment: Could you tell me in which cases FLAG_MUTABLE is used? I can not understand it

Comment: @JP711 No idea ...

Answer (score 3):

***Solutions to android 12 migration***

In Android 12 , there are some major code changes we need to do :

- We need to export all activities and other app components, we need to
  make the launcher as exported true `android:exported="true"`
- we need to set either immutable or mutable flags to our pending intents objects.

  `val intent = Intent(this, AlarmReceiver::class.java) val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this,  ALARM_SERVICE_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT )`

I recently migrated my apps and I listed complete migration journey with the solution to these crashes here

**solutions:** https://medium.com/native-mobile-bits/lets-use-android-12-migration-of-our-android-apps-to-android12-api-31-af329b6829d0

**solutions:** I have also shown my project migration to Android 12 at my [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/c/NativeMobileBits). where i fix all these issues here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X9IfLFLaVKI

Answer (score 0):

This is one of very Strange error for most old developer
**Below 3 Solution for** that

1.**android:exported'** property set
Your activity/service/receiver in your AndroidManifest.xml of your app or in any library is using intent-filter then it should have android:exported tag specified explicitly.

```
     <activity
                android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
                android:exported="true"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>



  

   <service
        android:name="com.example.ServiceControl"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"/>
```

2.**Targeting S+**
if you Targeting Targeting S+ please

```
PendingIntent activity;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                    0, new Intent(this, Your Class.class),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        } else {
            activity = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                    0, new Intent(this, Your Class.class),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }
```

3.**Last Magic Solution if above not work**
add Below line in build.gradle

implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'