# BroadcastReceiver does not work on Android 12

Tags: xamarin.forms, broadcastreceiver, android-12

In my Xamarin Forms project I have:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Permission = "RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED",
    Exported = true,
    Enabled = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] {Intent.ActionBootCompleted})]
public class GeofenceReceiver: BroadcastReceiver
```

I use it for GeofenceTransitionEnter and GeofenceTransitionExit events.
I also have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permissions.

But OnReceive method is not called on API 31. I have not this problem with lower APIs.

[Android 12 targetSDKVersion 31 challenges (Broadcast Receiver, Pending Intent) Crash Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70935464/android-12-targetsdkversion-31-challenges-broadcast-receiver-pending-intent-c) - doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added something like this into GepfencePendingIntent:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)
    } else {
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    }
```

I found it here: https://www.flybuy.com/android-12-pendingintent-mutability-and-geofences

Answer (score 0):

I have done a sample to test. And it worked well, the `OnReceive` method will call a few minutes after the device restarted.

The receiver:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Permission = "RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED",
    Exported = true,
    Enabled = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
    public class GeofenceReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            //launch our activity
            if (intent.Action == "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")
            {
                Toast.MakeText(context,"Device Restart",ToastLength.Long).Show();
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,typeof(ForegroundServiceDemo));
                intent1.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                context.StartForegroundService(intent1);
            }
        }
    }
```

The foreground service:

```
[Service]
    public class ForegroundServiceDemo : Service
    {
        private string NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "1000";
        private int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
        private string NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME = "notification";

        private void startForegroundService()
        {
            var notifcationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                createNotificationChannel(notifcationManager);
            }

            var notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            notification.SetAutoCancel(false);
            notification.SetOngoing(true);
            notification.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Mipmap.icon);
            notification.SetContentTitle("ForegroundService");
            notification.SetContentText("Foreground Service is running");
            StartForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification.Build());
        }

        private void createNotificationChannel(NotificationManager notificationMnaManager)
        {
            var channel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME,
            NotificationImportance.Low);
            notificationMnaManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            startForegroundService();
            return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;
        }
    }
```

The AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.START_FOREGROUND_SERVICES_FROM_BACKGROUND" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

I added the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` into the AndroidManifes.xml, because if I just added it in the `[BroadcastReceiver]`, the receiver will not work. So you can also try to add it in the AndroidManifes.xml.

In addition, you can create a new project to test my code. It worked on Android 12.0 emulator when I tested it. Finally, if it still not work, could you please show the code in the `OnReceive` method? Maybe the `OnReceive` method was called, but the code in it can't run background such as start an activity.

Comment: I have already solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Mine has not worked on Techno phones (11, 9 & 8.1) thus far. This is my original question and as you can see, everything in onReceive appears to be ok. Is techno firmware causing the issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75173799/xamarin-android-broadcast-receiver-is-being-fired-properly-after-boot-completion I tried it out on a vivo android 12 phone and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

on Targeting S+ for Pending intent below code work

For Activity

```
PendingIntent  pendingIntent ;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                    0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent. FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        }else {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                    0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }
```

For Broadcast

```
PendingIntent mediaButtonReceiverPendingIntent;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            mediaButtonReceiverPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
                    0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent. FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        }else {
            mediaButtonReceiverPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
                    0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }
```

for Service

```
final PendingIntent deleteIntent  ;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            deleteIntent = PendingIntent.getService(service,
                    0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent. FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        }else {
            deleteIntent = PendingIntent.getService(service,
                    0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        }
```